# How to mock a model method from unittesting a django view?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I am trying to mock a downstream function call in order to get my unittest for a DRF view to pass.

I have a create() method in my model, that is calling an external upload_files() function.  I am trying to figure out how to mock the upload_files() call (but from a test of my views)

Since the view calls the serializer, and the serializer calls the model, I need to figure out the correct namespacing in order to mock the path.  Here is my code which shows what I'm TRYING to do, however I think, the path being passed to mock.patch is incorrect.

Receiving this error when I run the unittest

```
ERROR: test_post (tests.api.views.test_stage_execution_view.StageExecutionViewTest)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp.models.stage_execution.StageExecution'; 'myapp.models.stage_execution' is not a package
```

unittesting a view from a drf api:

```
# myapp/tests/api/views/test_stage_execution_view.py

class StageExecutionViewTest(APITestCase):
    @mock.patch('myapp.models.stage_execution.StageExecution.create.upload_files', side_effect=mocked_upload_files)
    def setUp(self, arg):
        self.stage_execution = StageExecution.manager.create(
            stage="test",
            job_execution="test",
            time_start="2018-12-20T12:05:00.258797-08:00",
        )

    @mock.patch('myapp.models.stage_execution.StageExecution.create.upload_files', side_effect=mocked_upload_files)
    def test_post(self):
        start_stage_execution_payload = {"bla"}
        response = self.client.post(
        "/api/v2/stage_execution", start_stage_execution_payload, format="json"
    )
        assert response.status_code == 201
```

models:

```
#myapp/models/stage_execution.py

class StageExecution(JsonableModel):
    stage = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    job_execution = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    time_start = models.DateTimeField()

class StageExecutionManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return StageExecutionQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def create(self, **kwargs):
        from myapp.tasks import upload_files
        upload_files()
```

serializer:

```
# myapp/api/serializers/stage_execution_serializer.py

class StageExecutionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = StageExecution
        fields = (
            "stage",
            "job_execution",
            "time_start"
```

views:

```
# myapp/api/views/stage_execution_view.py

class StageExecutionView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = StageExecutionSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return StageExecution.manager.all()

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()

    if queryset.exists():
        serializer = StageExecutionSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to mock **upload_files**:

```
@mock.patch('myapp.tasks.upload_files')
def setUp(self, mocked_upload_files):
    mocked_upload_files.return_value = ""  # You can change here to get return value you need
```